# Add black outline for different geom_point shapes on DESeq2 PCA

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, rna-seq

I am running a PCA with the DESeq2 package and would like to obtain a black outline on the shapes which are already based on an observation.The round ones work, but the other shapes do not.

Examples such as [Make stat_ellipse {ggplot2} outline geom_point fill color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61236758/make-stat-ellipse-ggplot2-outline-geom-point-fill-color)
or [Place a border around points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437442/place-a-border-around-points) have data plotted as one only shape.

It is hard to give a reproducible example as it has previously performed a PCA on a big dataset, but this is what I have run the following:

```
ggplot(pcaData, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = dFe, shape = location))+   
geom_point(size=5)+  
geom_point(aes(PC1, PC2, color = dFe, shape = location), shape= 21, colour="black", size= 5)
```

I believe the key is on the coding of that new layer of `geom_point`

[image]

Running `scale_fill_manual I get the following`

```
ggplot(pcaData, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = dFe, shape = location))+   
geom_point(size=5)+  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22,23))
```

[image]

Comment: Just a quick thought, did you try plotting geom points with black color of some bigger size and again plotting geom points with color of smaller size?

Comment: I edited the image, so the size of the black outline is the same and coincides with the round shapes, but not with the triangles and squares, does this make sense?

Comment: `shape = 21` is overriding the shape aesthetic. Remove it. Use a `scale_shape_manual` to provide hollow (or bordered) shapes matching the locations.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I edited the post, the outline changes but the fill is now gone...

Comment: @Ecg So provide one. — See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, use `scale_shape_manual`, and provide a `fill` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(pcaData, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, fill = dFe, shape = location)) +
    geom_point(color = 'black', size = 5) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(21L, 22L, 23L))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
ggplot(pcaData, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, shape = location))+   
  geom_point(size=7) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, color = dFe, shape = location), size=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a good option! But the problem is when overlapping datapoint they don't show the full outline. But thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. @konrad-rudolph 's answer is the best.